Second Derivative of Antisymmetric Tensor Vanishes?
Consider the rank two antisymmetric tensor field defined over some manifold with metric $g$ (named $F$ because I did this work for E&M):
$$F^{\alpha \beta}=-F^{\beta \alpha}$$
Now consider acting two covariant derivatives on it:
$$\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha \beta}$$
Now we'll rewrite it two ways:
$$\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha \beta}= \nabla_\alpha \nabla_\beta F^{\beta \alpha}=-\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha F^{\beta \alpha}$$
We can combine these two write:
$$\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha \beta}=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta-\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha)F^{\beta \alpha}$$
This is just the commutator of two derivatives which we can represent using our Riemann curvature tensor:
$$\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha \beta}=-\frac{1}{2}(R_{\alpha \beta \mu}^{\quad \: \:\; \beta}F^{\mu \alpha}+R^{\quad \: \:\; \alpha}_{\alpha \beta \mu}F^{\beta \mu})$$
Now we can rewrite this in terms of the Ricci tensor (and use the antisymmetry of $R$ on the first two indices) to get:
$$\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha \beta}=-\frac{1}{2}(R_{\alpha \mu}F^{\mu \alpha}-R_{\beta \mu}F^{\beta \mu})$$
The Ricci tensor is then symmetric in its indices so we can write:
$$\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha \beta}=-\frac{1}{2}(R_{\alpha \mu}F^{\mu \alpha}-R_{\mu \beta}F^{\beta \mu})$$
But these indices on the right are dummy so we can rewrite to get:
$$\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha \beta}=-\frac{1}{2}(R_{\alpha \mu}F^{\mu \alpha}-R_{\alpha\mu}F^{\mu \alpha})=0$$
It seems to me like this shows that if we take two derivatives of an antisymmetric tensor we get 0 regardless of the metric. For me this is confusing because I don't see why this result would be the case. So I have two-ish questions. Firstly, is this result even correct? If it is correct is there any intuitive explanation for why this would be the case?

$\nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha \beta}$ is $J^\beta$ up to a multiplicative factor. What do you know about $\nabla_\beta J^\beta$?

$\nabla_i\nabla_j F^{ij}\sim \ast dd\ast F$, so this boils down to $d^2=0$.

Related question on Math.SE: Second Covariant Derivative Identity
